# Ionic 2/3 - Easy way of ignoring other application/android directories when scanning device

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm developing a gallery like app that allows users to select image/s from their phone and send to a kiosk. When the application loads it basically scans the whole devices for folders containing images and puts those folders into an album object. By Default iv set the scan to ignore all hidden directories (.directoryName), however iv noticed that the application also scan all the system directories like Android and other application folders; which significantly slows down the process.

Is there a way to ignore certain folders by a flag? or should I just set the scan manually to ignore the "android" directory and put up with some silly results? My other option is to only scan common known spots - which I'm not really keen on as I don't want to limit users options.

Any advice would be great! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [**native file plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/). It has so many options to `select/deselect` folder paths in the device.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

Comment: I'm already using the file plugin ".lisDir" to access the external root directory, as far as I know that's the only way. My question was more directed at - is there some sort of flags or metaData that informs you if the folder is application directory or system directory. I did notice ignoring the "android" directory greatly improved the search time. That should probably do that trick.

Comment: Yes, It is a huge directory (i.e. `android`). You need to search very specific places where you need it. Otherwise, it'll take a lot of time unnecessary.

Comment: `is there some sort of flags or metadata that informs you if the folder is application directory or system directory` **No.** You need to use publicly exposed `Instance Members` for that.